# Laravel 5: Middleware before & after into routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have two Middlewares: beforeCache & afterCache, boths registered on Kernel.

I want to call them into routes in this order:
1. beforeCache
2. myController
3. afterCache

If I define a route like this:

```
Route::get('especies/{id}', [
    'middleware' => 'beforeCache', 
    'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod', 
    'middleware' => 'afterCache', 
]);
```

beforeCache don't executes because afterCache is redefining the same array key middleware.

How should I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'll assume you're using 5.1 in this, but what you're doing is essentially trying to define an array of attributes on the route. The brackets `[]` are just a shorthand version of saying `array(...)`.

From the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware) specifically the Before / After Middleware you simply just need to return a certain way.

For Before middlewares you do your code and return the next request after your code executes.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Perform action

    return $next($request);
}
```

For After middleware you handle the rest of the request and then your code executes and finally return the response.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    // Perform action
    return $response;
}
```

The route would end up looking like this,

```
Route::get('especies/{id}',[
    'middleware' => [
        'beforeCache',
        'afterCache'
    ],
    'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod'
]);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
class BeforeMiddleware implements Middleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Do Stuff
        return $next($request);
    }

}

class AfterMiddleware implements Middleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        // Do stuff
        return $response;
    }

}
```

1-The before middleware operates and then passes on the request.

2-The after middleware allows the request to be processed, and then operates on it